# Play Framework 2.3 and javascript websocket client library

Tags: scala, websocket, playframework-2.3

I have installed the new Play Framework 2.3 with Scala 2.11, and I will build an application with websocket.

The server with scala in quite simple code:

```
object TestWebSocket extends Controller {

  def mysocketservice = WebSocket.acceptWithActor[String, String] { request => out =>
    TestSocketActor.props(out)
  }
}
```

the route.conf is:
GET     /wsk/testwebsocket                 controllers.TestWebSocket.mysocketservice

now i need a Javascript code for connect my page with the scala code, what javascript library can I use? I have seen a socket.io, but seems work only with node.js server.

I know than I can use a WebSocket directly, but i will using a library like socket.io for the compatibility with the old browser.

Can someone help me? 
Thank you very much

Comment: If someone is interested, there is a project for use socket-io with scala and netty, I think is possible intregrate it into play framework: https://github.com/mrniko/netty-socketio

Answer (score 1):

try out this javascript. This is the standard way to do it on Chrome, Safari, Mozilla etc.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function WebSocketTest(){
        if ("WebSocket" in window){ 
        var ws = new WebSocket("@routes.controllers.TestWebSocket.mysocketservice().webSocketURL()");
        ws.onopen = function(){
            // Web Socket is connected, send data using send()
            console.log("connected");
            ws.send("Message to send");
        };

        ws.onmessage = function (evt){
            var received_msg = evt.data;
            console.log(evt.data);
        };

        ws.onclose = function(){
            // websocket is closed.
            alert("Connection is closed...");
        };
        }else{
            // The browser doesn't support WebSocket
            alert("WebSocket NOT supported by your Browser!");
        }
    }
WebSocketTest();
</script>
```

Let me know how it goes.

Comment: Thank you Dario, I'm using a WebSocket directly, but it isn't a good idea for the compatibility with the old browsers. I hope than in the future socket.io will be compatible with websocket of playframework >=2.3. Thank you

Comment: You may want to use something like EventSource if that's the case... is like a Comet socket.

Answer (score 0):

You don't necessarily need a client side library to take advantage of WebSockets. Mozilla provides solid documentation of the [WebSockets API here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/WebSockets).

With that said, if you want visitors on older browsers to be able to take advantage of your WebSocket functionality, you may want to look into projects such as [SockJS](https://github.com/sockjs/sockjs-client) that can gracefully fallback to inferior (but better supported) protocols if need be.

Comment: Yes, I use a WebSocket directly, but it isn't a good idea for the compatibility with the old browsers. I hope than in the future socket.io  will be compatible with websocket of playframework >=2.3. Thank you

Comment: Note that I also provided a link to SockJS which can provide the compatibility with older browsers that you require. [More info can be found here](https://github.com/sockjs/sockjs-client).

Answer (score 0):

I use graceful websocket. It is very intuitive and hides all the complexity behind.

https://code.google.com/p/jquery-graceful-websocket/

```
// open socket using standard syntax
ws = $.gracefulWebSocket("ws://localhost:9000/soc"); //use wss for https
ws.onmessage=onSocMsg;

function onSocMsg(event){
  var jsonObj=json.fromString(event.data);
  alert(event.data);
}
```